# Connecting to local database from Android studio emulator

Tags: android, postgresql, jdbc, android-emulator, database-connection

I am trying to connect in a Postgres database from an android java app. Postgres server and android studio emulator are running on the same machine. I am getting this exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:281)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218)
at com.example.dbtestapp.DatabaseHelper.getConnection(DatabaseHelper.java:19)
at com.example.dbtestapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

The code of connection class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper {

    private static String URL = "jdbc:postgresql://10.0.2.2:5432/postgres";
    private static String USER = "postgres";
    private static String PASSWORD = "1111";

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
    }
}
```

And the main class code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView text = findViewById(R.id.text);

        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DatabaseHelper.getConnection();
            text.setText("good");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            text.setText("BAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

While I was trying to fix it, the following was done:

1. Checked and added user-permisions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

2. Edited pg_hba.conf, added two connections:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    all             all             192.168.1.68/32         trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0           md5
```

3. Turn off Firewall Windows in all three network types.
4. Checked project proxy settings (set on "no proxy", connected succesfull)
5. Tried all of Ipv4-addresses i got in ipconfig (bc hope is leaving me), and 192.168.1.68 from pg_hba.conf
6. Added 2 rules (TCP and UDP protocols) for 5432 port

Still doesn't work..

I also have run only java code in Intellij and got the connection and data from my db.
I also have internet connection on emulated device

Comment: `Something unusual has occurred ...` That is not very informative. Try to start a thread and try to connect in the run() of that thread. 10.0.2.2 should do it.

Comment: You did not bind the postgress server to an ip address?

Comment: `also have run only java code in Intellij ` On the same machine? Try from a different machine in local network.

Comment: @blackapps  i've got the connection and data! I'am so happy right now, Thank you! 
But have no idea why it is working. Is that android limitation?
upd: still same machine, only started in thread